# In scrapy css selectors how do i get a strings ' ' instead of a sub-string [ ]

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors

I can't figure out how to get a string out of a selector

I've tried

```
response.css('.size_list a::text').extract()
```

I get

```
['L', '1X', '2X', '3X', '4X', '5X']
```

Here is the code

```
    <span class="size_list">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="itemAttr current" title="L" data- 
         value="L">L</a>

         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="itemAttr" title="1X" data- 
           value="1X">1X</a>    

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="itemAttr" title="2X" data- 
         value="2X">2X</a>    

       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="itemAttr" title="3X" data- 
         value="3X">3X</a>    

       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="itemAttr" title="4X" data- 
        value="4X">4X</a>    
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="itemAttr" title="5X" data- 
        value="5X">5X</a>   
    </span>
```

What I want is "`'L', '1X', '2X', '3X', '4X', '5X'`"

Answer (score 1):

This is not something for the extraction code to do, this is something you should do with regular Python code once you have the extracted data:

```py
>>> extracted_data = ['L', '1X', '2X', '3X', '4X', '5X']
>>> ', '.join("'%s'" % value for value in extracted_data)
"'L', '1X', '2X', '3X', '4X', '5X'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to do it directly in the selector. An alternative could be to get it first as a list and to transform it into a string with something like this:

```
size_list = response.css('.size_list a::text').extract()
string_size_list = ', '.join(size_list)
```

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Getting the data into a list? Or making a string out of them?

Answer (score 0):

**To obtain the first occurrence of the elements**

```
response.css('.size_list a::text').extract_first()
# or
response.css('.size_list a::text').get()
```

**This should work**

```
item_list = response.css('.size_list a::text').extract()
one_string = (', ').join(item_list) # this work
```

[image]